# Why is JavaScript calculating some cosine and sine values as a decimal, but for others an integer?

Tags: javascript, coordinates, trigonometry

I'm using `x + (distance * Math.cos(orientation * Math.PI))` and `y + (distance * Math.sin(orientation * Math.PI))` to calculate `xx` and `yy` respectively.

`50 + (20 * Math.sin(1 * Math.PI))` and `50 + (20 * Math.cos(0.5 * Math.PI))` equal `50`

but

`50 + (20 * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI))` and `50 + (20 * Math.cos(1.5 * Math.PI))` equal `49.99999999999999`?

I expected `50` here too. Is it a javascript quirk I need to use `Math.ceil()` with (calculating coords on a canvas)?

Comment: This is quirk will all the programming languages in the world.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: javascript does not differentiate between ints and doubles, everything is just a `number`

Comment: Canonical duplicate: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)